# cshtml option value to writeline in controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

cshtml

```cshtml
@model List<ViewModel.Participant>;
<form asp-action="PostNewBasketballPlayer" asp-controller="Dashboard" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select>
        @{
                if(Model != null)
                {
                    foreach(ViewModel.Participant i in Model)
                    {
                        <option value="@i.ParticipantId">
//line 11
                            @i.ParticipantFirstName @i.ParticipantLastName id number: @i.ParticipantId
                        </option>
                    }                    
                }
        }
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info mt-5" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
  using System.Linq;
  using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

  namespace LeagueProject.Models
  {
      public class ViewModel
      {
       private Context db;
       public ViewModel(Context context)
       {
           db = context;
       }
       public ViewModel.Participant participant { get; set; }
       public List<Participant> allParticipants { get; set; }
       // List<Participant> allParticipants = db.Participants.Include(i=>i.Parent).ToList();

       public class Participant
       {
           [Key]
           public int ParticipantId { get; set; }

           [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
           [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "must be at least 2 characters")]
           public string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }

           [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
           [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "must be at least 2 characters")]
           public string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }

           [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
           public string ParticipantGender { get; set; }

           // [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
           // [Range(8, 20, ErrorMessage="this league if roages 8-19")]
           // public int ParticipantAge { get; set; }

           [Required(ErrorMessage="Need a date of birth")]
           [DataType(DataType.Date)]
           public System.DateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }

           public int UserId { get; set; }
           public User Parent { get; set; }

           public List<MMLeagueParticipant> allLeagues { get; set; }
       }
    }
}
```

context.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace LeagueProject.Models
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<League> Leagues { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ViewModel.Participant> Participants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MMLeagueParticipant> ParticipatingKids { get; set; }

    }
}
```

DashboardController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("postNewBasketballPlayer")]
    public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer(ViewModel.Participant newParticipant)
    {

        if(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId") == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("newParticipant");
        Console.WriteLine(newParticipant);

        Console.WriteLine("newParticipant.ParticipantId");
        Console.WriteLine(newParticipant.ParticipantId);

        ViewModel.Participant newP = db.Participants.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ParticipantId == newParticipant.ParticipantId);
        Console.WriteLine("newP");
        Console.WriteLine(newP);
        if(newP != null)
        {
        // bunch of if checks that have their own returns.
        }
        if(newP == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("null");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("skips all if checks because newP was null");
        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Dashboard");
    }
```

My cshtml does show the correct ParticipantId inside the options in line 11. So I know the Id that I'm passing in my form is correct.

but when I try console.WriteLine's in my Dashboardcontroller I get back the following in my command terminal:

```
newParticipant
LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel+Participant
newParticipant.ParticipantId
0
newP
null
skips all if checks because newP was null
```

it also returns 0 for any option I select when writelining newParticipant.ParticipantID.

regardless of what ever i set as my value i always get the same response in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net core bind model data with `name` attribute,try to add `name` attribute to your `select` like this:

```
<select name="ParticipantId">
```

Here is a demo:

View:

```
@model List<ViewModel.Participant>;
<form asp-action="PostNewBasketballPlayer" asp-controller="Dashboard" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="ParticipantId">
        @{
                if(Model != null)
                {
                    foreach(ViewModel.Participant i in Model)
                    {
                        <option value="@i.ParticipantId">
//line 11
                            @i.ParticipantFirstName @i.ParticipantLastName id number: @i.ParticipantId
                        </option>
                    }                    
                }
        }
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info mt-5" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("/Dashboard/postNewBasketballPlayer")]
        public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer(Participant newParticipant)
        {

            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: i wrote`            Console.WriteLine(newParticipant.ParticipantId);
            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Dashboard");`  in the HttpPost but i got LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel+Participant in the terminal instead of the idNumber. i also changed the option to value=@i so it would return the entire model.

Comment: You only have a `<select>`in the view form?Do you have other code in your view?`<select>` will only return one value,it will not pass an entire model to backend.

Comment: I only have the select. So when you are calling it; youre calling it as a Paricipant model in the IActionResult. shouldn't it be an int since we can't pass an entire model

Comment: Can you show me your httpost request data?